# how to have JSch handle follow-up commands ?

Tags: java, jsch

I have a case where I need to telnet to a device and show its configuration .

If I was to run this manually step by step, following are the details:

> ```
> telnet 10.105.234.56
> ```
>
> Trying 10.105.234.56... Connected to 10.105.234.56. Escape character
>   is '^]'.
>
> S524DF4K15000002 login: `admin`
>
> Password: Welcome !
>
> S524DF4K15000002 # `config system dns`
>
> S524DF4K15000002 (dns) # `show`
>
> config system dns
>         set name "8.8.8.8" end
>
> S524DF4K15000002 (dns) #

where the `grey` part are my inputs.

And by this java code,

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            String command = "config system dns";
            String command2 = "show";
            String host = "10.105.234.56";
            String user = "admin";
            String password = "";

            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);;
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.connect();

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
            InputStream input = channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();

            System.out.println("Channel connected to machine " + host + " server with command: " + command ); 
            try{
                InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(input);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
                String line = null;

                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputReader.close();
            }catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I was able to:

```
1. telnet 10.105.234.56" with user as: "admin" 
2. run "config system dns" command.
```

But where I may add this follow-up `show` command in this java code ?

The OS of this device is little simple, that I can not pipe both commands into one piece to run.

Comment: When I have previously done this I have had one Thread for reading and one Thread for writing and I have used the `shell` channel.

Comment: I am quite new to this implementation. Is there a example I can take a look.  In my case, the 2nd cmd can only be executed following the 1st one.  It should not be in a separate Channel, I believe.

Comment: Heaps of examples at http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/

Comment: *It should not be in a separate Channel,* I did not say so.